# How to Find ID for controls on excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have to write VBA script to select any item from Menu Bar from the code, but it did not work.

Please find below the code and suggest what should be the correct code.

```
Sub selectMenu()
    Application.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").Controls("View").Controls("Arrange All").Execute
End Sub
```

Comment: What version of Excel?  What happens when you run your code?  Nothing, or do you see an error?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `>=xl2007` then you can use the `ExecuteMso` to click on the `Arrange All`

```
Sub selectMenu()
    Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("WindowsArrangeAll")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Windows.Arrange
```

The parameter could be either of `xlArrangeStyleHorizontal`, `xlArrangeStyleCascade`, `xlArrangeStyleTiled`, `xlArrangeStyleVertical`.

ref: (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221833(v=office.11).aspx)